# Fill Font Characters with White?

Tags: text, fonts, unity-game-engine

My font has an empty "interior". As show below:

Font with white background:

[image: White Background]

Font with blue background:

[image: Blue Background]

How can we make the "interior" of the text always be white, without using a background? I'll be using the Unity game engine.

And of course, I can't edit the .ttf file. As @itchee pointed out: A TTF font is always in one color only. It can only specify opaque and transparent parts (technically, only the opaque parts are specified and everything else is transparent). The application that displays that font can chose one single color for the opaque part. But it cannot make "some parts black and some parts white". My question is how to achieve what I want **using the Unity game engine**. Any C# scripts are welcome.

As @fafase said, a filling algorithm, for each character, looking for surrounded zone and filling them would be ideal.

Comment: What font is this? Is it a font you made or you got or you got from built in windows/mac? Or is this just an image?

Comment: "fonts" can be achieved many ways in something as complex as a game engine; you need to include a screen shot of your setup at a minimum to give people an idea what you are doing.

Comment: @ʇolɐǝzǝɥʇqoq This is a font that I downloaded from the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use bitmap fonts.
They aren't supported natively by unity, so you can use an asset from the asset store called [CJFinc: Bitmap Font Tools](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/27216).  If you aren't willing to pay that much I found a nice tutorial [here](http://www.benoitfreslon.com/unity-generate-and-import-a-bitmap-font-with-a-free-tool).

But so far, my most flexible idea, and probably what I would do is to create a second font that you can place behind your first font.  You would keep your original font at a black color. The second font would be simple shapes that fit the shape of your fill, and that you set to whatever color you want. Here's a quick sketch of what I mean:

[image: explain]

You can use [fontforge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) to create your custom fonts.  It might take you quite a bit of time, but It will then work consistently, simply, and without many changes to your scripts.

Comment: Unfortunately, this option is  **gimmicky**. As @fafase said, a filling algorithm, for each character, looking for surrounded zone and filling them would be ideal. Any other solid ways are welcome.

Comment: A fill algorithm is also **gimmicky** (a better word might be hacky, workaround, or polyfill).  A fill algorithm would be unnecessarily complex, slow, and difficult to make.  Don't over complicate it for yourself. If you do, **you will run into issues and complications**.  How would you make a complex color-detecting filling algorithm vs how fast could you fill in the shapes and creating a second font? The choice seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: I understand, but with your suggestion, I have to create a specific fill for every single character...

Comment: That should be much less work than creating a so called fill algorithm.

Comment: Anyway, you would have to read pixel values form a tff font(so the algorithm would know where to fill in with your color), but it can't read those values since a ttf font file is actually an svg.   From my knowledge I don't even think such an algorithm is possible.  And don't wait for someone to make you a script. If you want someone to make you a script hire them for money.  This is a site for helping programmers, not doing their work for them.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to edit TTF fonts, you cannot make the "background" white.

TTF fonts can only specify opaque and transparent parts  (technically, only the opaque parts are specified and everything else is transparent). The application that displays that font can chose one single color for the opaque part. But it cannot make "some parts black and some parts white".

Comment: So, how can I achieve what I want with the Unity game engine?

Comment: Only way I can think of is using a sprite map for each character you want to use and compose your text off the sprites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that option wouldn't be efficient and would waste space...

Comment: But that is your answer, this is what was told to you a while back when you originally posted this question. You are pending on a solution that does not seem to exist. So either you use what is told to you or give it up. If you feel like it, you can come up with a filling algorithm, for each letter, it looks for surrounded zone and fills them. Make the bounty 500 and maybe someone will spend some time on it.

Comment: @fafase I'm giving up all my points for the bounty, and it's been 5 days since I asked the question... I really need an answer, because my project's deadline is in a few days! :( Your filling algorithm idea sounds interesting by the way.